# Keep a Servlet/JSP web site always on SSL?

Tags: security, https

How to I keep a site always on SSL with padlock symbol always exists. Is there any way to optimize the page for SSL in JSP and Servlets ?

Just tell about jsp and servlet optimization so answer do not make long discussion

Answer (score 1):

You can tell if your site is in secure mode using [ServletRequest.isSecure()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#isSecure%28%29).  If you find that the request is not secure, then issue a redirect to the secure version using [HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect(location)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29).

As far as optimizing for HTTPS, the only thing that I typically do is make sure that external resources (images, JavaScript, CSS) are all fetched securely.  If you try to load HTTP resources into a HTTPS page, browsers will complain.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are asking but here is my suggestion based on what i understand from your question.

To keep your website always on SSL, you need to install an SSL certificate on your server by generating CSR for your domain.